# Is there an app or service that allows a customer to log in and submit design requests?

Tags: looking-for-a-script

I have several clients with several requests coming into my email.  Is there a website that would give me the ability to receive client design requests and then schedule them for me?

Comment: Schedule what exactly? Do you need the clients to pick a time slot before emailing you or submitting a design request? Isn't it just as easy to receive an email and set a schedule in your email clients calendar?

Comment: I could use email and then manually enter that into my invoice app (Harvest).  But being a lazy programmer, I was hoping there might be a service out there on the Web that would allow a designer's customers to login and add tasks they want done on their webpage, which would then load into the designer's work queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha sorry but if you're a lazy programmer i'm not sure i'd want you working on my projects. That said since you've now told us what app you're using to manage work you should consider reviewing the API http://www.getharvest.com/api/tasks#create-task now if you weren't lazy you could use any existing php login authentication library, integrate with harvests API and now your clients can login to a protected website create a task for their project, view existing tasks etc.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  As for being a "lazy programmer," I think you may have misinterpreted what I meant, one blogger (Philipp Lenssen) put it perfectly, "Lazy, because only lazy programmers will want to write the kind of tools that might replace them in the end. Lazy, because only a lazy programmer will avoid writing monotonous, repetitive code – thus avoiding redundancy, the enemy of software maintenance and flexible refactoring. Mostly, the tools and processes that come out of this endeavor fired by laziness will speed up the production."

Comment: @BillWItt well said, i've been working with out sourced programmers and finding a good one is 1 out of 10. Hope that helps seems to be the best way to go about it and not too difficult.